# getting error with Selenium using google colab

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to do webscraping using selenium in Google colab and getting error

[image: Here is my code]

webpage says I have to enable Javascript and disable adblocker if any. I tried to enable javascript by putting

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
```

but still get error. However My friend was able to do same using conda. Is there any way to get it correct in Google colab.

[![**Getting error webpage**: "please enable javascript and disable adblocker if any"][2]][2]

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should not use images as you have here

Comment: Can you share the entire errorstack trace  ?

Comment: I don't get error in webpage. I should be getting desired HTML page instead I get webpage saying Please enable java-script and disable adblocker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to chrome being headless. Due to that I was not able to verify that I "Not a Robot".  Alternative approach can be used to solve this problem. for eg. running code in laptop instead of collab.